# Videoview not showing up afer loading a bitmap from asset?

Tags: android, android-videoview, bitmapfactory

I am using Android, and have a videoview that plays movies from res/raw just fine using the following code:

```
public static void startVideo(String moviename) {
    playingVideo = true;
    final String name = moviename + "x264";
    instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            instance.mVideoView.bringToFront();
            instance.mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String uri = "android.resource://" + instance.getPackageName()
                    + "/raw/" + name;
            instance.mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
            instance.mVideoView.requestFocus();
            instance.mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
```

However, if I call the following function inside my activity's onCreate method with a valid asset image filename as the argument (ie, "backdrop.jpg"), the video view no longer seems to show up:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream is;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        is = assetManager.open(strName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

It does not matter if I even use the resulting bitmap in any code or not, it seems that the mere act of calling the above function somehow seems to cause the videoplayer to stop showing up.   Simply commenting out the line which does nothing more than call that function and store the result in a local variable causes the videoview to start showing up normally again.

Also, nothing else seems to be affected... I have a GLSurfaceView in my program, for instance, which shows up just fine.

I am very puzzled about this... and any assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution... turned out that what was happening was that the GLSurfaceView in my program was actually overlaying the videoview.   I'm still not sure why, since I was trying to explicitly brig the videoview to the top, but nonetheless, keeping the GLSurfacview hidden while I play videos seems to work acceptably.